# Smooth point of the quotient space obtained by Lie group action

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a Lie group acting smoothly and effectively on a smooth manifold $M$ and $\pi: M \to M/G$ the quotient map. Can we find a point $p \in M$ such that an open neighborhood of $\pi(p)$ is smooth?

Comment: Certainly if $G$ is compact - then $M$ contains an open dense set of such points.  I'm afraid I have no idea what happens when $G$ is non-compact....

Comment: @JasonDeVito Can you explain the compact $G$ case?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "open neighborhood of $\pi(p)$ is smooth", I'm assuming you mean "open neighborhood of $\pi(p)$ can be given the structure of a manifold for which $\pi$ is smooth in a neighborhood of $p$"

First, if $G$ is non-compact, then there may not exist such a point.  For example, consider the $G=\mathbb{R}$ action on $M = T^2 = \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ given by $t(\theta, \phi) = (\theta + t, \phi + \sqrt{2} t)$.  This action is smooth because it descends from a linear action on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and it is effective because $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

The orbits are dense, and so $M/G$ is has the property that each point is dense.  In particular, no point of $M/G$ can have a Euclidean neighborhood.

$ \ $

On the other hand, if $G$ is compact, then there must exist a $p\in M$ for which there is an smooth open neighborhood of $\pi(p)$.  In fact, there is an open dense set of points of such $p$ in $M$.  This is essentially the content of Theorem 3.4.6 of these notes: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/math661/LectureNotesLee.pdf